# Find and Delete text in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to find and delete all instances of the sentence "Use 0 to cut papers" in both tables and textboxes.

My code so far will delete the sentence from the textboxes but an error will appear:
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Delete' of object 'TextRange' failed

For tables, the sentence would not be deleted.

Any suggestions?

```
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long   

   For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
   For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    
        If shp.HasTable Then
            For i = 1 To shp.Table.Rows.Count
                For j = 1 To shp.Table.Columns.Count
                With shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                 Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="Use 0 to cut papers")
                 Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                   With foundText
                     .Delete
                End With
                Loop
                End With
            Next j
            Next i
         
         End If
         
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="Use 0 to cut papers")
            Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                With foundText
                    .Delete
                End With
            Loop
        End If
        
    
Next

Next
```

Comment: What happens if you adjust the `With shp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange` line to `With shp.Table.Cells(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange`?

Comment: I get an error message: Compile error: Method or data member not found

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to use the Replace method and replace the text you're searching for with "" (nothing):

```
Sub Test()
    Call DeleteTextLike("YOUR TEXT HERE")
End Sub

Sub DeleteTextLike(sText As String)

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim x As Long

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                For x = 1 To oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines.Count
                    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines(x).Replace sText, ""
                Next
            End If
        End If
        
        If oSh.HasTable Then
            With oSh.Table
                For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                        With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame
                            .TextRange.Replace sText, ""
                        End With
                    Next
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next    ' Shape
Next    ' Slide

End Sub
```

Comment: I did think of that. But the problem is that the sentence is the second of a few bullet points. So if I simply replace the text with a blank space, the bullet point will be there in front of an empty space.

Comment: Try adding a further test after doing the replace, along the lines of if the length of the paragraph containing the line is 0, delete it